# C++ does list.unique() resize the list?

Tags: c++, list, resize, unique

Does a call of unique() on a list also resize the list if repeats are found?

Comment: ... as opposed to `std::unique`, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. It removes the duplicate elements. So the size of the list changes as well.

Have a look at the documentation **[here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/unique/)**. It says:

> The elements removed have their destructors called and their iterators and references become invalid.

Note that in case of **[std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/)**,  while erasing an element, only the iterators and references to the erased element are invalidated [23.2.2.3/3].